# Is it legal to use alt+0160 for empty space in website development?

Tags: html

When i designing my site i came across a two empty space need for an alignment and i had use Alt+0160 for that and it looks fine and good. But i need to know that is this way  legal for designing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may look fine in your browser, with your specific font settings, but awful in other environments.

No, don't use characters for styling.

Answer (score 3):

In html you should use non-breaking space. You can code it using `&#160; or &nbsp;` , but try to use css instead of nbsp to style your website. It should behave better in all browsers. :)

Answer (score 2):

The page does not contain Alt+0160. It contains the NO-BREAK SPACE character (U+00A0) generated by the key combination Alt+0160 on Windows. The character is valid and often useful, but using it for visual formatting is usually not a good idea, partly because CSS lets you affect the formatting in much more fine-grained way.

When you use NO-BREAK SPACE, then using the character itself (as opposite to `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` or `&#xa0`) has the benefit and disadvantage of looking like a space in HTML source in most programs that you use for viewing it. It makes the content look cleaner, but it is difficult to notice when you need to (or *should*) pay attention to different space characters.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid `&nbsp;`, but it is a legal character and you won't face any issues because of it. I do, however, feel that using CSS's `margin`, `padding`, `text-indent`, etc (depending on what you're trying to accomplish) is a much neater way of doing the same thing.

If you do use it, I would recommend using `&nbsp;` instead of `Alt+0160` to make it clear that you are using them.